# Map drive in powershell through Scheduled Task without credentials

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to run a powershell backup script as a scheduled task, and as a part of this I need to map a network drive (before copying the backup to the remote host).

Now, this was working when I had it like this:

```
NET use $RemoteDir $RemoteUser $BackupPass
```

But due to security concerns, I can't keep the password in plain text, or anywhere on the server. So, my hope was that, since it's run as a scheduled task, 'NET' would be able to "inherit" the credentials from the user running the scheduled task, so that it could be run like this:

```
NET use $RemoteDir
```

But it doesn't seem to work, when I log the error I get:

```
The password is invalid for <RemoteDir>.

Enter the user name for <RemoteDir>':
```

So, my question is: Is there any way to get this to work? I.e. having NET use the credentials that the scheduled job is running with? Or do I need to find another approach?

Edit: Forgot to mention, the user running the scheduled task is a domain user, and it has access to the remote.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a domain account. Assign the account permissions to the share and NTFS directory. Set the task to execute under the account you just created.

Comment: Hmm... might've been worth mentioning that I'm using a domain account to execute the task, and it has permission to access the share. It still asks me for username/password though.

Comment: Ok, turns out this was the problem. The server admin hadn't added the permissions for the user as I though they had, but once they did, it worked out great!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the solution, but a work arround.
You can store a password in a file locked down to say "domain admin" like the suggestion above and follow the directions on this link:

http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/02/16/106518.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems weird, I manage station users from scheduled task without any problem, so it is possible to use the credentials. Maybe the `net use` is just misbehaving, have you tried using New-PSDrive instead?